# How to make a SearchView/filter on a custom ListView and add items in the underlying ArrayList using an EditText?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, searchview

I'm newbie in android, I really want to know how to make searchView or filter custom listView.
my listView has 1) ImageView and 2) TextView.
I have tried many tutorial about this, but the data are constant.

so, please help me

How to make a SearchView/filter on a custom ListView and add items in the underlying ArrayList using an EditText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest you start using Recycler view since it would be easier to do this functionality using it.
here is your starting point:

- [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)
- [RecyclerViewAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)
- [Creating lists with Custom rows](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)